# Xcode 12: How to distribute an app using an old iOS distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, keychain

I need to upload an app on the account of the client. From the client I received an `old iOS distribution certificate`.
How I can distribute an app with an *old iOS distribution certificate* on `Xcode 12`? 
I can't create a new *Apple distribution certificate* due to the reason that the maximum number of certificates has already been generated.
Currently, when I distribute with 'Automatically manage signing' I am receiving an error `missing the private key of the Apple Distribution Certificate`.

Should I try to use Manual signing instead? 
If yes, I never define a manual signing before, so maybe, someone can recommend me a relevant-updated tutorial.
In addition. [As have been said on Apple's site an old iOS distribution certificate might be supported.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes)
[image]

```
**Update: I resolved the issue by creating a new Provisioning Profile + Manual signing with an old iOS distribution certificate.
```

Comment: You will have to create a new certificate, Older one won't work anymore

Comment: singh.jitendra Thanks. I resolved the issue and updated the post with my solution.